# Exception Thrown Your project has triggered a breakpoint

Tags: c++, file-handling

I am working on a project in C++ file handling and already spend a lot of time to fix this bug but failed and looking for help.

### Here is my .txt file

```
SNO, Name, NoOfPeopleLiked
1, The Shawshank Redemption, 77 
2, The Godfather, 20        
3, Into The Wild, 35
4, The Dark Knight, 55      
5, 12 Angry Men, 44
6, Schindler's List, 33
7, The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King, 25
8, Pulp Fiction, 23
9, The Good, the Bad and the Ugly, 33   
10, The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring, 56
11, Lucifer, 1
12, 50 Shades of Grey, 1
```

I want to show top 5 rated movies with respect to `NoOfPeopleLiked` and it works perfectly when there is only **10 movies** in a file. But Whenever I add more movies in a file it shows **Project Movies Management System.exe has triggered a breakpoint** and then my compiler shows this `if (_Result) { _STL_VERIFY(!_Pred(_Right, _Left), "invalid comparator"); }`(BreakPoint).

### Code:

```
int movieRating()
    {
        try {
            auto StrTrim = [](string& str) {
                str.erase(0, str.find_first_not_of("\t\n\v\f\r ")); // left trim
                str.erase(str.find_last_not_of("\t\n\v\f\r ") + 1); // right trim
            };
            ifstream ifile("movies.txt");
            //string line;
            vector<string> lines;
            // Read all lines of file.
            while (getline(ifile, line)) {
                StrTrim(line);
                if (line.empty())
                    continue;
                lines.push_back(line);
            }
            if (!lines.empty())
                lines.erase(lines.begin(), lines.begin() + 1); // remove first header line
            vector<tuple<size_t, string, size_t>> data;
            regex re(R"((\d+)\s*,\s*(.+)?\s*,\s*(\d+))");
            for (auto const& line : lines) {
                smatch matches;
                if (regex_match(line, matches, re)) {
                    if (matches.size() != 4)
                        throw runtime_error("Matched line with not 3 elements: '" + line + "'!");
                    data.push_back(make_tuple(size_t(stoi(matches[1])), matches[2], size_t(stoi(matches[3]))));
                }
                else
                    throw runtime_error("Unmatched line: '" + line + "'!");
            }
            sort(data.begin(), data.end(), [](auto const& l, auto const& r) {
                return get<2>(l) >= get<2>(r);
                });
            int sum = 0;
            for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
                if (i >= data.size())
                    break;
                cout << (i + 1) << ", " << get<1>(data[i]) << ", " << get<2>(data[i]) << endl;
                sum = sum + get<2>(data[i]);
            }
            cout << "\n---------------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
            cout << "\nThe total number of people who have already rated the movies is : " << sum << endl;
        }
        catch (exception const& ex) {
            cout << "Exception: " << ex.what() << endl;
            return -1;
        }
    }
```

In short, I want to display top 5 movies with respect to `NoOfPeopleLiked` my code works perfectly for only **first 10 movies** in a file and throws an exception whenever the movies exceded from 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparators must return true if the first item is to be sorted earlier than the second item and false otherwise. This implies that the comparator must return false for **equal** items. Your comparator does not do this

```
return get<2>(l) >= get<2>(r);
```

Change to this

```
return get<2>(l) > get<2>(r);
```

You actually had quite a helpful error message.

Comment: @AhmarAamir Just noticed that you got that code from a previous SO answer. Oh well, I've added a comment there as well.

Comment: That's so kind of you @john . Thanks for helping